# UITableView move cell to last row when dropped on tableview footer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

With iOS 11 we have the new drag and drop API, which uses the existing `UITableViewDelegate` methods for reordering single rows within the same tableview. I use an empty view as the `tableView.tableFooterView` in order to hide the cell separators below the last actual cell. However, if there are only a few cells and the footer is shown, when trying to move a cell to the end position it can be awkward because the tableview footer doesn't accept drops.

Is there some way to use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath
```

or another method from `UITableViewDropDelegate` to redirect drops from the tableview footer to the last `IndexPath`?

The only other option I can think of is to make the footer a custom drop target, but that would resize the drop preview and change the code path for handling drops.

Comment: Make the tableView's Footer the drop target and inside the call back add the item to end of array and reload the tableView

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes, I thought of that, but I was wondering if there is a way to handle this without shrinking the cell (drop preview) so that it matches the normal reordering UI.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with the table view footer as a custom drop target. It turns out that the dragged cell doesn't resize until it leaves the bounds of the full table view, so this is a pretty smooth solution. The only significant difference is that with this approach the cell will animate from its original index instead of just dropping from the last drag position.

**EDIT** As requested, I found my original implementation and have pasted it below. There may be a couple other steps outside of this required for DND, I no longer recall. For context, `ItemsVC` contained a `UITableView` with 3 sections for overdue, todo, and done items. The done section may or may not be hidden by the user. Dropping an item in the footer for reordering was only supported if the done section was hidden.

```
// MARK: - Drop in TableView Footer

extension ItemsVC: UIDropInteractionDelegate {

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        let doneRowCount = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: PlannerItemGroup.done.rawValue)
        return session.items.count == 1 && doneRowCount == 0
    }

    /**
     Currently this only supports dropping a single SMItem or SMSimulatedItem that is already in the tableview.
     This is inteded to function as an extension of the method:
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
     */
    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
        guard session.items.count == 1 else {
            return
        }

        let todoItems = viewModel.plannerItems(for: .todo)

        //Cast the localObject as an SMPlannerItem
        guard let plannerItem: SMPlannerItem = session.items.compactMap({ (dragItem: UIDragItem) -> SMPlannerItem? in
            return dragItem.localObject as? SMItem ?? dragItem.localObject as? SMSimulatedItem
        }).first else { return }

        //PlannerItem must come from this tableView and not from the done section
        guard let sourcePath = viewModel.indexPath(for: plannerItem),
            sourcePath.section != PlannerItemGroup.done.rawValue
        else { return }

        let doneRowCount = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: PlannerItemGroup.done.rawValue)

        if doneRowCount == 0 { //Footer is below todo section
            print("Will move item to end of todo section")

            let destinationPath = IndexPath(item: todoItems.count - 1, section: PlannerItemGroup.todo.rawValue)
            movePlannerItem(plannerItem, from: sourcePath, to: destinationPath, moveRow: true)
        }
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidEnter session: UIDropSession) {
        print("Drop session did enter footer")
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
        return UIDropProposal(operation: .move)
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidExit session: UIDropSession) {
        print("Drop session did exit footer")
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidEnd session: UIDropSession) {
        print("Drop session did end")
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example how did you do it? I am currently trying to do the same thing for footer and "clear" part of tableview. I have drag and drop for tableview implemented, but all rows dropped not directly under the last row are returned to their original position.

Comment: @Nalov Have you created a custom footer view for the tableview and can you use its background color to confirm that the footer is covering the area where you are dropping the cell? Once you have that footer working, you can add drop support for it with logic for adjusting the cell index. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/making_a_view_into_a_drop_destination)

Comment: I have added an uibutton with a tag as a tableview footer. it does not have a background.  what do you mean "you can add drop support for it with logic for adjusting the cell index. –" this is the part that i am having trouble, can you give example of the logic? Currently i went with moveRow method - when it doesn't get destinationindexpath different from sourceIndexPath it will remove from array and add to the end. It works, but the moverow function animation shows that cell returns to original position. I disabled animation, but now it just appears at the end without nice animation.

Comment: @Nalov I reread your question and it sounds like you are asking about the awkward animation that happens when you drop it in the footer view. I'm afraid I didn't find a way around that, based on what I wrote in the last sentence of my original answer. I haven't touched this code in a couple years, so I don't think I can be of more help. Maybe SwiftUI will handle this better.

Comment: If you can find the code, please edit your answer with your code  as i would like to see your solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 ios 13.5

I ended up doing this.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    //remove animation when no different destinationIndexPath is there, meaning we moved over tableview area with no cells

    if sourceIndexPath == destinationIndexPath{
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    }
    else{
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
    
    
    myarray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    
    if sourceIndexPath != destinationIndexPath {
        myarray.insert(todo, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
        
    else if sourceIndexPath == destinationIndexPath{

        let therow = myarray.count
        myarray.insert(todo, at: therow)

        //just to add a litle delay before row appears at the end. othewwise looks ugly.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1) {
            self.topTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
}
```